# Help on "GROUP BY clause" error

Tags: max, aggregate-functions

Wish anybody can help me with this error "Column 'Sales.No_' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."...
I spent few days to understand this error but failed :(
My Query:-

```
SELECT SH.[No_], SH.[Sell-to Customer No_], SH.[Sell-to Contact No_],
SH.[Sell-to Customer Template Code], MAX (A.[Version No_]) 
FROM [Sales] AS SH 
LEFT JOIN [Sales Archive] A ON (SH.[Document Type] = A.[Document Type] 
                 AND SH.[No_]=A.[No_] 
                 AND SH.[Doc_ No_ Occurrence]=A.[Doc_ No_ Occurrence]) 
WHERE (SH.[Document Type]='0' and SH.[Order]='1')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "MAX" function requires a group by if you have an non-aggregate columns.
So you will need to add a group by sh.[No_]....

Also I have reformatted your query so I can read it easier -hope that is ok-

```
select SH.[No_]
, SH.[Sell-to Customer No_]
, SH.[Sell-to Contact No_]
, SH.[Sell-to Customer Template Code]
, MAX (A.[Version No_]) 
from [Sales] AS SH 
    LEFT JOIN [Sales Archive] A ON 
        (SH.[Document Type] = A.[Document Type] 
          AND SH.[No_]=A.[No_] 
          AND SH.[Doc_ No_ Occurrence]=A.[Doc_ No_ Occurrence]
        ) 
where (SH.[Document Type]='0' and SH.[Order]='1')
group by SH.[No_]
       , SH.[Sell-to Customer No_]
       , SH.[Sell-to Contact No_]
       , SH.[Sell-to Customer Template Code]
```

Comment: Hi Philip..

tried that but then same error occurs but to different field which is 'Sales.Sell-to Contact No_'

I actually don't really get the meaning of this "non-aggregate column"...i'll find out about this and make sure i understand it :)

Comment: I changed my query to "select SH.[No_],SH.[Sell-to Customer No_],SH.[Sell-to Contact No_],SH.[Sell-to Customer Template Code],MAX (A.[Version No_]) from [Sales] AS SH LEFT JOIN [Sales Archive] A ON (SH.[Document Type] = A.[Document Type] AND SH.[No_]=A.[No_] AND SH.[Doc_ No_ Occurrence]=A.[Doc_ No_ Occurrence]) where (SH.[Document Type]='0' and SH.[Order]='1') group by SH.[No_]"

then I got this error msg "Column 'Sales.Sell-to Customer No_' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Try select SH.[No_]
, SH.[Sell-to Customer No_]
, SH.[Sell-to Contact No_]
, SH.[Sell-to Customer Template Code]
, MAX (A.[Version No_]) 
from [Sales] AS SH 
    LEFT JOIN [Sales Archive] A ON 
        (SH.[Document Type] = A.[Document Type] 
          AND SH.[No_]=A.[No_] 
          AND SH.[Doc_ No_ Occurrence]=A.[Doc_ No_ Occurrence]
        ) 
where (SH.[Document Type]='0' and SH.[Order]='1')
group by A.[Version No]
I think that my group by in the answer was all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've used an aggregate function (MAX), so the remaining selected columns must also be using aggregate functions or in a group by clause.  eg

```
select SH.[No_],SH.[Sell-to Customer No_],SH.[Sell-to Contact No_],
SH.[Sell-to Customer Template Code],MAX (A.[Version No_])
from [Sales] AS SH LEFT JOIN [Sales Archive] A ON (SH.[Document Type] = A.[Document Type]
AND SH.[No_]=A.[No_] AND SH.[Doc_ No_ Occurrence]=A.[Doc_ No_ Occurrence])
where (SH.[Document Type]='0' and SH.[Order]='1')
group by SH.[No_],SH.[Sell-to Customer No_],SH.[Sell-to Contact No_],
SH.[Sell-to Customer Template Code]
```